# How can I print a function from JavaScript to html

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, web-deployment

I'm trying to make a out of '*' and I got the code right because it works in the console but when I try to print it in the html document it does not work

```
function Pyramid() {
    let rows = 9;
    let output = '';
    for (let i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        for (let j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            output += '*  ';
        }
        console.log(output);
        return output;
        output = '';
    }
}
document.getElementById('pyramid').textContent = generatePyramid();
```

```
<body>
    <div id="pyramid"></div>
    <script src="../script.js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? Does it not print? Does it not get in to the function?

Comment: you're calling a function named `generatePyramid();`

Comment: First look at the location of your script file. You have included `../script.js/script.js` two times! Is `generatePyramid` is same function as `Pyramid` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so there are a few minor issues here.

- Your function is called `Pyramid` but you are calling `generatePyramid`.
- You are returning at the end of the first row because `return output` is within the for loop.
- In the console you are outputting using `console.log` which will give you a row in the console... however for the HTML you are just dumping it all so it would be a continuous row of stars instead of one row at a time.

In the code below I've fixed these issues and made it so it outputs each row in a `<p>`. There are numerous ways to achieve this result and improve upon it, but I think this is what you were aiming for.

```
function generatePyramid() {
  let rows = 9;
  let output = "";
  for (let i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    output += "<p>";
    for (let j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      output += "* ";
    }
    output += "</p>";
  }
  return output;
}

document.getElementById("pyramid").innerHTML = generatePyramid();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

document.getElementById("pyramid").innerHTML='generatePyramid()';